# The 'ApacheCordovaToolsPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I just installed VS 2015 Professional and Tried to install Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, it completed successfully.
However, when I try to get to create a new Project for the same, it just gets stuck there.

Then if I open a new instance of VS 2015 and go to Tools --> Options --> Apache Cordova, I get following error message:

> ---------------------------
>   Microsoft Visual Studio
>   ---------------------------
>   The 'ApacheCordovaToolsPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\Anant\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.
>
> Continue to show this error message?
>   ---------------------------
>   Yes   No
>   ---------------------------

I tried repair and uninstalling and reinstalling as well. But no luck.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the error lines from ActivityLog.xml here, so we can analyze what goes wrong. Did you have installed Visual Studio 2013 in parallel? On what machine did you install VS 2015: Win 8.1/10?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear about you're trouble. I suspect you are hitting a known issue which we have fixed and documented here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135

Can you try the following workaround steps to see if it fixes the issue?

If the Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development are still installed:

1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2015, click Change.
2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
3. Deselect the feature Tools for Universal Windows App Development.
4. Select Tools for Universal Windows App Development again, and click Update.

If you have already uninstalled the Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development:

1. Reinstall Tools for Universal Windows App Development.
2. Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:

   - Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, such as, vs_community.exe.
   - Open a command window, and run the following command: 
     vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden /passive

Hope that helps. If not, I would very much like to see the xml log. Please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can get in touch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, however before you replied I actually reinstalled whole VS 2015, after uninstalling it. And it solved the issue for now.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. We fixed setup so that a clean install would also fix the problem. Glad you're unblocked.

Comment: Link is now broken