# The 'ApacheCordovaToolsPackage' package did not load correctly and more errors

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I cannot work with Cordova Tools for Visual Studio anymore. I am getting the following error on opening a Cordova project:
'The 'ApacheCordovaToolsPackage' package dit not load correctly.'.

I have already tried the solutions suggested here at SO, including, but not limited to:

- [The 'ApacheCordovaToolsPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945352/the-apachecordovatoolspackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)
- [Error: SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741405/error-setsite-failed-for-package-apachecordovatoolspackage)

Those solutions did not solve my problem.

To sum-up what I have already tried:

- Create a new, clean Cordova project;
- Delete the .vs folder in the Cordova project's folder;
- Install ALL the Visual Studio project types;
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator;
- Removing Visual Studio (and a clean Visual Studio install afterwards);
- Removing Cordova Tools (via Add/Remove) and reinstalling;
- Clearing the cache, located at: 'C:\Users[username]\appdata\local\microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache';
- Execute the installer with the options '/modify /installselectableitems Javascript' (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741405/error-setsite-failed-for-package-apachecordovatoolspackage));
- Execute the installer with the options as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945352/the-apachecordovatoolspackage-package-did-not-load-correctly).

I think it has something to do with a wrong path definition, as the error logged in the ActivityLog.xml, specifies.

Error #1:

```
<entry>
<record>714</record>
<time>2017/01/15 18:09:04.318</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not find a part of the path &apos;C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies\Low&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path &apos;C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies\Low&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Telemetry.Cookies.CookieReader.GetCookiesFromFolders(List`1 paths, String browser)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Telemetry.Cookies.CookieReader.GetCookies()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Telemetry.Reporting.solutionListener_ProjectOpened(Object sender, ProjectEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Telemetry.Reporting.SendMissedProjectOpenEvents()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Telemetry.Reporting..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, SolutionEventsListener solutionListener)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Telemetry.Reporting.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
<guid>{317A330D-8757-4084-8526-E8A1D165433D}</guid>
<hr>80070003</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

Error #2:

```
<entry>
<record>512</record>
<time>2017/01/14 19:29:06.740</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>CreateInstance failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;1) No exports were found that match the constraint: &#x000A;&#x0009;ContractName&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&#x000A;&#x0009;RequiredTypeIdentity&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage.configurationServiceProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage.configurationServiceProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition atomicComposition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.CompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.SatisfyImportsOnce(ICompositionService compositionService, Object attributedPart)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage..ctor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;1) No exports were found that match the constraint: &#x000A;&#x0009;ContractName&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&#x000A;&#x0009;RequiredTypeIdentity&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage.configurationServiceProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage.configurationServiceProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.Definitions.ICordovaAppConfigurationServiceProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition atomicComposition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.CompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.SatisfyImportsOnce(ICompositionService compositionService, Object attributedPart)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.ApacheCordovaToolsPackage..ctor()</description>
<guid>{317A330D-8757-4084-8526-E8A1D165433D}</guid>
<hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Some extra information:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Comment: Could you please try run VS as administrator?

Comment: I already did, I forgot to put it in the sum-up of things I already tried. It does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a post on MSDN, and got contacted by the team responsible for the Cordova Tools. Apparently, the following folder was missing on my system: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies\Low

By starting Internet Explorer, the missing folders got recreated and subsequently, I did not receive any errors anymore. My problem is now solved.